# condition in tableview method of UITableViewController in swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make section header conditional in following code so that i can add a "+" button on one section header.Following is my method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let customSecHeader = UIView()

    if (section == 0)
    {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        let addButton = UIButton()
        titleLabel.text = "\(self.section[section]) (\(self.items[section].count))"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Left

        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,140,30)
        addButton.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
        addButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        addButton.frame = CGRectMake(60,5,10,10)

        customSecHeader.addSubview(titleLabel)
        customSecHeader.addSubview(addButton)

    }
    else
    {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()

        titleLabel.text = "\(self.section[section]) (\(self.items[section].count))"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center

        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,140,30)

        customSecHeader.addSubview(titleLabel)

    }

    return customSecHeader

}
```

But this code is not working.When i tried to debug this method i found that this method was executed once with section = 1 but i have 2 section in my table.

Comment: Have you implemented heightForHeader: ?

Comment: No, is it necessary to implement it ????

Comment: Im not sure if the viewForHeader will be called if there is not height, I could be wrong but it should be implemented anyway.

Comment: You are right @sean. It worked, Thanks.